# ASP File Upload control not working within a previously hidden panel

Tags: asp.net

I'm utilizing an ASP file upload control on a web page, and I want it hidden until the user wants to upload a file, so the update panel's visible property is false by default.  When the button prompting the file upload is clicked, the upload control shows, and a file can be selected, but when the upload button is clicked, an error shows that the PostedFile property of the upload control show "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", even though a file path is visible in the conrrol.  This works if the upload control is never hidden.  Here is the source:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updUploadTestDoc" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlUploadTestDoc" runat="server" GroupingText="Upload Test 

Document">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" SkinID="FieldLabel" Text="Select File to Upload : " />&nbsp;&nbsp
                <asp:FileUpload ID="uplUploadFile" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" text="Upload" SkinID="ConfirmButton"  />&nbsp;&nbsp
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancelUpload" runat="server" Text="Cancel" SkinID="CancelButton"  />
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've tried hiding/showing updUploadTestDoc, pnlUploadTestDoc and the upload control itself, all with the same results. The VB code where the error occurs is:
strAttachmentPath = pUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName

I'm using VS 2010, framework 4.0.  This is my first post here, so let me know if more info is needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't retain/assign value in FileUpload control. This is because of due to browser security reasons. The file submission is possible only on the first submission to server. You can't retain or assign a value to it.

In an UpdatePanel the same thing happens. An Ajax post submission will happen asynchronously and thus the browser won't retain the file. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591705/how-does-an-updatepanel-actually-work)

And the solution is to keep the fileUpload **outside** the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Retaining or assigning values is not the problem here.  Once a file is selected, the PostedFile property of the upload control should not be null.

Comment: you can't retain fileupload value inside an update panel. you can place the file upload outside the panel. I was just trying to quote IT general. I would say its impossible to upload the file from updatepanel.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use asp:fileupload inside update panel, it's kinda of issue in asp file upload ,
so get it out of the update panel and it will work perfectly

Comment: Sorry, but moving it outside the update panel doesn't fix the problem.  Besides, I'm using the file upload control inside an update panel nested in an Ajax tab control elsewhere (Same as the case in question, by the way.  Forgot to mention the tab control on the initial posting) and it works fine.  The ONLY difference there is I'm not hiding that control or any of it's containers.